# Google Protobuf Import Proto File

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm having trouble importing a proto file into another resulting in an error in the webpage.

*Proto to host everything*

```
import "proto_to_import.proto";
```

Now, if I append the host to the import statement it will work fine

```
import "localhost:8080/proto_to_import.proto";
```

Is there a way to make it so I don't have to append the host info into the statement? I assumed the first import statement would just look for a file in the same directory as itself and import that proto file but that's not the case apparently.

**EDIT**

The exact error message shown on the browser console is as follows:

`vendor.js:5 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://network_config.proto/'`

The proto files are being used within an AngularJS app to transfer data through a WebSocket.

Comment: What do you mean the "webpage" fails? Normally `.proto` files are processed by the `protoc` command-line tool. Does it fail? What arguments are you passing to it? What is the exact error message? What programming language and Protobuf implementation are you using?

Comment: @KentonVarda I've edited my question. I didn't create the proto files just using them within my application. I'm just using them to construct messages to send over a websocket.

Comment: `.proto` files aren't meant to be loaded at runtime. They are meant to be passed to the `protoc` command-line tool which generates code in your preferred language.